# how to redirect page using jquery on button click in serenity Application Template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to redirect page using jquery on button click in serenity application template .
I  have Serenity application template now i want to redirect page from chtml page using jquery on button click ?

Comment: To which page you need to navigate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's simple,try this

```js
$('#someButton').click(function() {
    window.location.href = '/some/new/page';
    return false;
});
```